# How to reset reCaptcha widget

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

How can i reset reCaptcha widget after pressing the button.

my code is :

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha recaptcha" id="recaptcha-widget" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXX"></div>
```

Comment: Reset in what way?

Comment: reset after pressing a button

Comment: You can refresh the page? Or wait for it to time out?

Comment: What button? This question makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```